# how to use relational operators on handlebar {{@index}} variable?

Tags: html, if-statement, handlebars.js

how are we going to use conditional operators on the {{@index}} variable such that we can print only the even records form the json.

{{#each options}}

if( {{@index}} % 2 == 0 ) //

{

## print record

}

else

{

## this is a odd record

}

{{/each}}

Answer (score 3):

Logic like you're trying to do has to be in a helper function.  You can't put relational operators like that directly into a handlebars template.  It is designed that way on purpose.  Helpers are very easy to create and use.  See http://handlebarsjs.com/#helpers more more info.

FYI, a very common helper I use is an even/odd helper:

```
hbs.registerHelper("stripes", function(index) {
     return (index % 2 === 0 ? "even" : "odd");
});
```

Which I use like this to get an "even" or "odd" class name put in a row:

```
<div class="row {{{stripes @index}}}"> 
    ... other content
</div>
```

I don't quite understand what you're trying to do in your example, but you could hide all the odd records with a simple CSS rule or you could put more logic into the helper.